# Perturb very small numeric values (between 0.001 and 0.999)

Tags: php, math, random

I have a table with numeric values stored as `decimal(8,3)` in MySQL.  I'm pulling these values for display, however I need to slightly alter the values first (with [data perturbation](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25013/data-perturbation)).   For example:

```
a: 0.123
b: 0.011
c: 0.003
```

would be perturbed and shown as:

```
a: 0.125
b: 0.010
c: 0.001
```

if I drew the same report a second time, I might get something like:

```
a: 0.119
b: 0.005
c: 0.005
```

The idea is to make the perturbation unpredictable from value to value, while keeping the value close to the original.   It may increase by .001, then decrease by .003 on the next value.

At no time should a value become negative or 0.  If I have .001, that should be randomly perturbed upwards so that it is .001 or higher afterwards.

I'm currently using this to perturb values greater than 1, and it is working OK.  When passed a value below 1, my perturbed values are not making sense.

```
    $perturbed = $v + ( mt_rand( $v*(-1), 40) / 100 );
```

For example, if $v is .04, $perturbed could wind up being .99, which is statistically out of range for the given $v.

The data set is relatively large, so whatever solution needs to not cost a lot of processing power.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just figure out a min/max allowable range for each value's peturbation, then have `mt_rand($allowable_min, $allowable_max)`?

Comment: I could randomize the mt_rand inputs based on size of passed $v.  Working on that now.